# Typescript complier options "Lib" doesnt work as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, lib

I was trying to understand how lib works. I target as polyfill the es5 features and declared in lib only the "dom" declarations. Promise isnt part of es5 and compiler should have raised an error because i havent declare it in lib option. But i get no error, is something wrong here?

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs":true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom"],
    "outDir": "./typescriptDist"
  }
```

**index.ts**

```
console.log(new Promise(() => {}));
```

**eslint**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  env: {
    browser: true,
  },
  globals: {},
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
  },

  extends: [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
  ],
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", { endOfLine: "auto" }],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 0,
    "react/function-component-definition": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": 0,
    "max-classes-per-file": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": 0,
    "class-methods-use-this": 0,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": 0,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ["/*.*"],
};
```

Comment: Throws an error for me. How are you running this?

Comment: Through webpack, using ts-loader. Also i use eslint, which it doesnt give either an error. See the updated post.

Comment: Well on typescript playground this errors, so in your environment either tsconfig.json isn't honored, or you have a library that adds their own global definition for promises.

Comment: And how  do i find this?

Comment: it seems that @types in node_modules are responsible.